# How do I import JavaScript files in Rails 3?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, coffeescript

I've just started working with Ruby on Rails, and I'm having some difficulty calling JavaScript functions from HTML. I'm using Rails 3.2.13, Ruby 1.9.3, and RubyMine 5.0.2.

I have a CoffeeScript file called "home.js.coffee" in "app/assets/javascripts/" that apparently compiles to "application.js" in the same folder. In "app/views/home/", I have the HTML file for the home page "index.html.erb". I have a function in "home.js.coffee" called `cubes()`:

```
cubes = alert math.cube 3
```

This is really basic for now. I want to get comfortable first.

This is an object called `math`:

```
math =
    cube: (x) -> x* square x
```

I created a button in `index.html.erb` that should theoretically call this function:

```
<button onclick="cubes()">Try it</button>
```

The problem is getting it to find the JavaScript file. What needs to be in index.html's head? What needs to be in application.html's head?

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that the function is in another scope. If you compile the CoffeeScript with the `-b` option, that will make the functions globally available, but the simple solution would be:

```
root = exports ? this
root.cubes = -> alert math.cube 3
```

and then you can call `cubes()` from your HTML.

Comment: or even to use any other js library like prototype, but that wasn't even the question, and the advise should be on the question, not on the answer